# Custom post carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a post carousel (it's being used on a WordPress theme initially), but I've adapted it to just HTML/CSS/JS one.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dingo_d/pen/doNyMw)

```
var $carousel = $('.post_excerpt_carousel');

$carousel.each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    var outer_width = $(window).outerWidth();
    var container_width;

    if (outer_width > 1145) {
        container_width = 1170;
    }

    if (outer_width > 960 && outer_width < 1145) {
        container_width = 960;
    }

    if (outer_width < 960) {
        container_width = parseInt((9/10)*outer_width,10);
    }

    var duration = $this.data('duration');
    var li_number = $this.find('li').length;
    var $ul = $this.find('ul');
    var $li = $ul.find('li');
    $li.removeClass('active');

    if (outer_width < 760){
        $li.css('width', container_width);
        $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
        if ($li.eq(2).hasClass('active')) {
            $li.eq(2).removeClass('active');
        }
    } else if (outer_width > 760){
        $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
        $li.eq(2).addClass('active');
    }

    var list_width = $this.find('li').outerWidth(true);
    var left_offset;

    left_offset = parseInt(list_width - (outer_width - container_width-42)/2, 10);

    $ul.css({'display': 'inline-block', 'width': li_number * $this.find('li').outerWidth(true) + 'px', 'left': -left_offset + 'px'});


    var not_active_no = $this.find('li').not('.first').not('.last').not('.active').length;
    var not_active_width = not_active_no * $this.find('li').outerWidth(true);

    $this.on('click', '.carousel_next', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($this.find('li.last').prev().hasClass('active')){
            return;
        } else {
            var $a = $('.active', $this);

            if (!$a.next().hasClass('last') && !$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $a.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            }

            if (!$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $ul.animate({
                    left: parseInt($ul.css('left'), 10) - $ul.find('li').outerWidth(true),
                }, duration);
            }
        }

    });

    $this.on('click', '.carousel_prev', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($this.find('li.first').next().hasClass('active')){
            return;
        } else {
            var $a = $('.active', $this);

            if (!$a.prev().hasClass('first') && !$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $a.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
            }

            if (!$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $ul.animate({
                    left: parseInt($ul.css('left'), 10) + $ul.find('li').outerWidth(true),
                }, duration);
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Keep your code styling uniform everywhere**

1. Line 3 with your function declaration after `$carousel.each(` doesn't follow the same styling as used later on in line 50 when declaring the callback function for the `click` event listener here `$this.on('click', '.carousel_prev', function (e) {`.
2. Your `if`'s/`else if`'s/`else`'s don't use the same format. You go from `if () {` to `if (){`.

**Simplify your if statements**
You should change:

```
if (outer_width > 1145) {
    container_width = 1170;
}
if (outer_width > 960 && outer_width < 1145) {
    container_width = 960;
}
if (outer_width < 960) {
    container_width = parseInt((9/10)*outer_width,10);
}
```

to use a combination of `if()`, `else if()`, and `else()`:

```
if (outer_width > 1145) {
    container_width = 1170;
} else if (outer_width > 960) {
    container_width = 960;
} else {
    container_width = parseInt((9/10)*outer_width,10);
}
```

Another example of this is here:

```
if (outer_width < 760){
    $li.css('width', container_width);
    $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
    if ($li.eq(2).hasClass('active')) {
        $li.eq(2).removeClass('active');
    }
} else if (outer_width > 760){
    $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
    $li.eq(2).addClass('active');
}
```

It can easily be written as:

```
if (outer_width < 760) {
    $li.css('width', container_width);
    $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
    if ($li.eq(2).hasClass('active')) {
        $li.eq(2).removeClass('active');
    }
} else {
    $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
    $li.eq(2).addClass('active');
}
```

This also fixes a problem with a dead spot that happens if `outer_width` is equal to 760. Unless this is unwanted behavior, which I see no reason why it should be, then the second option is the better way to go. This is an implementation of the TF-Statement or binary condition, where if it's not one, it always has to be the other. Sorry, I've been in math theory recently. :-)

**Use simpler and more concise code**
Where you define `var not_active_no = $this.find('li').not('.first').not('.last').not('.active').length;`, you could have easily written a single cleaner and concise `$.not();` like so: `var not_active_no = $this.find('li').not('.first, .last, .active').length;` or you could've just settled with a single CSS call like so: `var not_active_no = $this.find('li:not(.first, .last, .active)').length;`.

Comment: Welcome to Codereview, KingCodeFish. Fine first answer.

Comment: You're very welcome. :-)